# create a select input with menus created on a custom options page

Tags: php, customization, menus

In a custom wordpress page, I want the user to select a desired menu from a custom options page.

Something like that

[image]

Here I record the fields, now I only have one field type text to do some tests

```
function register_my_cool_plugin_settings() {
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'menu_site' );
}
```

Now, I create the input registered above

```
<td>
  <input type="text" name="menu_site" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('menu_site') ); ?>" />
</td>
```

I want a select field with data coming from the wordpress itself, in my case, I want it to list the menus created by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi see [wp_get_nav_menus()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menus/)

You can set `$args` parametr. The same as `$args` to `get_terms()` function.

function will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [name] => Menu 1
            [slug] => menu-1
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
            [taxonomy] => nav_menu
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => Menu 2
            [slug] => menu-2
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
            [taxonomy] => nav_menu
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
        )
)
```